# How to apply a function to each value of an array and store the results

Tags: authorization, abac, open-policy-agent, rego

I am new to Open Policy Agent and the Rego language. I have an array of strings. Each of those strings needs to have some operation performed on them so they may be in the appropriate format for use later. Is there a way to apply a function to each element in the array and then store those processed elements as a result array?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps `newList := myFunction(oldList[_])` or use a [list comprehension](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#comprehensions) to filter the items `newList := [newValue | oldValue := oldList[_]; newValue := myFunction(oldValue)]`

Comment: @IronMan Thank you for your response. It really helped out!

Answer (score 1):

That would normally be done with an [array comprehension](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#array-comprehensions):

```
a := ["a", "a", "b", "c"]

b := [x | y := a[_]
          x := upper(y)
          x == "A"]

# b == ["A", "A"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your explanation was very helpful